# Change space between Routs and copper pours in Altium PCB designer

Tags: pcb, altium, polygon

How Can I change the distance between Polygon pours and routs in *Altium PCB designer*?

[image]

Update 1: 
Actually I'm newbie on Altium so posted the PCB with default clearance value (0.245 mm) and larger value (0.345 mm) respectively. I think it conflicts with routs through *U1* and *U2*, which routs are so close to pads.

[image]

[image]

Update2: I was changing the clearance between track and polygon so it didn't work. I changed clearance between polygon and other parameters and it's working.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along the top: **Design > Rules**

A window will open, along the left: **Electrical > Clearance > Polygons**

Change the **Minimum Clearance** to whatever you would like it to be.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but the distance is same as before. When the Minimum Clearance is changed to lower value nothing happens and when it's changed to a larger value the polygon color changes to green.

Comment: Not sure about Altium, but you probably have to rerun DRC or update polygons or something like that.

Comment: Final step: repour all polygons.

Comment: What @ThePhoton said (which I assumed you would have known/tried after nothing changed). All good but.

Comment: @STWilliams,  I've changed the rules and deleted the polygon and placed it again, but it doesn't work, don't know what's going wrong. I added pictures.

Comment: There might be language issues that makes me not understand, but to me it seems like the clearance change worked? Are you really trying to clear the DRC violations that comes from the pin pitch of U1 and U2 being smaller than your clearance?